# How to add documentation comments for a Dictionary/KeyValuePair in C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Is there  a proper way of describing a Dictionary type variable or a KeyValuePair with documentation comments in C#.

Something like this,

```
/// <summary>
/// User credentials
/// </summary>
/// <key>username</key>
/// <value>password</value>
private static Dictionary<string, string> credentials;
```

Comment: There's no specific tag listed in [the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-tags) or [the Sandcastle help](https://ewsoftware.github.io/XMLCommentsGuide/html/4268757F-CE8D-4E6D-8502-4F7F2E22DDA3.htm).

Comment: Oh! That's a shame. Can't we even put something like `<param>` ? @Richard Deeming

Comment: `<para>` applies to a method or indexer parameter. `<typeparam>` applies to a generic type parameter, but only on the open generic type / method. There's no standard tag to document the type parameters of a closed generic type.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you really need here, but maybe like this?

```
/// <summary>
/// Dictionary of passwords by username
/// </summary>
Dictionary<string,string> Passwords
```

Good names are really your best doc, which you can supplement with the summary tags (or others as well).

Alternatively, you could make a custom class that inherits Dictionary and then provide a custom `.Add(username,password)` method and add comment tags to that.  Or same thing, but Extend Dictionary instead.

Comment: @NeWi-SL: if you have the urge to inherit from `Dictionary`, you may want to go through this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt.  Similar reasoning holds here.  I wrap dictionaries all the time (and, remember, with the _Collection Initialization Pattern_ you can make your class's construction/initialization look like a Dictionary's).  I can't think of a good reason to extend one

Comment: Thanks a lot you both @Flydog57 I have updated the question little bit. Hope it might help you to get an idea of what I am trying to say.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, there is no way to document such types in a structured way. I do this with a free text inside a `<value>` tag. This tag is primarily designed for properties but it's displayed in Intellisense also for fields.

My comment would look as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// User credentials.
/// </summary>
/// <value>The collection of credentials where the key is a username and the value is a password.</value>
public static Dictionary<string, string> credentials;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try this too